# Multiple, simultaneous MPI_Bcast to pass struct-of-arrays

Tags: c, mpi

What's a performant, clear and correct way to broadcast a struct of arrays from the root rank to all others? Will the code below achieve this? I want the broadcasts to simultaneously utilize as much communication bandwith as possible.

I'm afraid that I don't have the option to restructure the data, for example, into an array-of-structs.

```
float arr1[16];
int arr2[16];
char arr3[16];
//...fill arr1-3 with great data. Establish rank ID's, etc
MPI_Request req[3];
MPI_Status status[3];
MPI_IBcast(arr1, 16, MPI_FLOAT, root_rank_ID, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
MPI_IBcast(arr2, 16, MPI_INT, root_rank_ID, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
MPI_IBcast(arr3, 16, MPI_CHAR, root_rank_ID, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[2]);
MPI_Waitall(3,req,status);
//check status to ensure the outcome is OK
int importantData = importantFunction(arr1,arr2,arr3);
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for pointing that out. The function call has enough information in it not to need the if statements I had included.

Comment: You can create a derived datatype that describes your 3 arrays, and then `MPI_Bcast()` it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, wouldn't this mean copying the SoA into an AoS, passing it, then converting back to a SoA? I would like good performance. However, if you feel that this may lead to better performance on the communication side, please indicate why the snippet I posted wouldn't perform as well.

Comment: you call `MPI_Ibcast()` 3 times, and that can be be reduced to a single call if your derived datatype describes the SoA. There is no AoS, not explicit nor implicit, in the picture.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, OK, would arr1-3 need to be adjacent to each other in memory? I'm new to MPI so I'm struggling to understand how to construct the derived datatype without using an AoS.

Comment: `MPI_Type_create_struct()` and `MPI_BOTTOM`

Comment: Note `MPI_Bcast()` is likely faster than `MPI_Ibcast()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, OK, I was not aware that this could be done. I am new to MPI and it shows. I'm reading more about derived datatypes now.